# Same Bitmap in multiple Objects memory managment

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I need to pass the same `Bitmap` to a bunch of Objects which are later put into an `ArrayList`.

The Bitmap is 1024x512 pixels big and I'm always passing the same `Bitmap` Object to about ~1000 Objects.

I need to do this because every Object does something with the `Bitmap` later in the code.

Is this safe to do memory-wise?

Comment: How many times will you call new Bitmap?

Comment: And make sure to remove the objects from the list when they're no longer needed. "Forgetting" to remove obsolete objects stored in collections is a common way to produce memory leaks in Java.

Comment: @HannoBinder is calling ```.remove(xyz)``` enough? Or should I invoke the garbage collector?

Comment: @EricS. What do you mean by "call new Bitmap"? Only one ```Bitmap``` is created (using ```BitmapFactory.decodeFile```) and this ```Bitmap``` is passed to the Objects

Comment: Yes, removing object references from the collection is enough. The GC will then take care of releasing the memory when necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is safe in the sense that it won't create 1000 bitmaps. Java won't pass around all 1024x512x3 bytes of bitmap, only the value of the reference of the one bitmap you are passing around.

Very important on how Java passes objects: [java passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)